# ASP.NET MVC 4 get value from different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, models, url-parameters

I have a class "Student" and other class "scoresheet".

Each Professor should be able to fill up a scoresheet for each student. I have been able to create, list, edit the scoresheet with using the default scaffolding options.

However, when a professor is directed to homepage/students he is presented with the default option such as create, edit, delete, and i would also like to add a "score" option, that would go to the create option of the scoresheet model/controller.

I was able to do this, but i would like to know how i can pass the StudentID/name to the scoresheet controller in order to know for which student the scoresheet is being created.

Please advise.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to send the id as a parameter and call the Controller Action